# MySQL query involving multiple rows, access one based on max value

Tags: mysql, sorting

So I am trying to have a single script that accesses all values of a table based on a particular id. The script returns the values in an array using PHP:

**Example:**

```
// Select data from DB 
$query = 'SELECT * FROM experiences WHERE user_id = ' . $id; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error($link));

// Not sure this actually creates a 2D array...
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

However, I realize that I need modified results for particular tasks, such as the row where a particular value is the highest.

How would I go about doing this, and does $array actually hold all the rows and respective fields?

Answer (score 1):

TRY

`'SELECT * FROM experiences WHERE user_id ='.$id.' HAVING MAX(column_name)`

OR

```
 "SELECT max(column_name), other column...
  FROM experiences 
  WHERE user_id =".(int)$id
```

Comment: This is great, but not exactly what I was looking for. This would require me to alter my script

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have cleaned `$id` properly you can do this

```
// Select data from DB 
$query = 'SELECT * FROM experiences WHERE user_id = ' . $id; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error($link));

$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
```

and `$data` will contain the 2D array you're looking for.

If you want the row where a particular value is highest I suggest either looking into `ORDER BY` or `MAX()` depending on your needs.

Comment: Hmmm, but how do I sort the PHP array for the maximum value?

Comment: Look into ORDER BY its exactly what you need to sort.